# Merge two rows in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here's the code I am using:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int rowIndex = gridView.Rows.Count - 2;
                                  rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
    {
        GridViewRow gvRow = gridView.Rows[rowIndex];
        GridViewRow gvPreviousRow = gridView.Rows[rowIndex + 1];
        for (int cellCount = 0; cellCount < 2; cellCount++)
        {
            if (gvRow.Cells[cellCount].Text.ToUpper().Trim() ==
                                   gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Text.ToUpper().Trim())
            {
                if (gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan < 2)
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan = 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    gvRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan =
                        gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].RowSpan + 1;
                }
                gvPreviousRow.Cells[cellCount].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output of this code looks like [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9ZRF.png).
Here, red Circle indicates the problem in output. I don't want row merge when the cells to the left columns are different. For example, controlling office should not merge if bank is different.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
           RowStyle-BackColor="White"
           runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound = "OnRowDataBound">
           <Columns>
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
               <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
           </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("Country"), new DataColumn("Name") });
        dt.Rows.Add("USA", "John Hammond");
        dt.Rows.Add("USA", "Suzanne Mathews");
        dt.Rows.Add("Russia", "Robert Schidner");
        dt.Rows.Add("India", "Vijay Das");
        dt.Rows.Add("India", "Mudassar Khan");
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowIndex > 0)
        {
            GridViewRow previousRow = GridView1.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex - 1];
            if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text == previousRow.Cells[0].Text)
            {
                if (previousRow.Cells[0].RowSpan == 0)
                {
                    previousRow.Cells[0].RowSpan += 2;
                    e.Row.Cells[0].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this code will merge only first column  row. i need to merge first 2 column  row

Comment: my above code is working fine only problem is when  row of second column is same but row of first column is different

Comment: check with this code for change of column name    for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (row.Cells[i].Text == previousRow.Cells[i].Text)
                {
                    row.Cells[i].RowSpan = previousRow.Cells[i].RowSpan < 2 ? 2 : 
                                           previousRow.Cells[i].RowSpan + 1;
                    previousRow.Cells[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }

Comment: your code is 100% Correct and working . but issue is /n